# Oblique Chebychev Net

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

What is the differential equation of lines on the "oblique Chebychev Net" formed  by connecting boundary points on a base circle to an apex point not on circle axis? ( base circle center to apex oblique connecting line is inclined at $\alpha \ne \pi/2) $ to the plane of circle.

Is negative Gauss curvature $K$ constant for this distorted surface?  How is the Sine-Gordon equation modified?

Do lines seen in the idealized model still have zero normal curvature when internode distance tends to zero in the limit?

If $K$ is not constant, then how should the bottom circle be redefined as a new distorted oval for same constant $K$?

[image: ObliqueChebyNet]